# How does one prove that if $Γ⊢¬∀xψ$ then $Γ⊢¬∀x¬¬ψ$ using the Hilbert System?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The text for my course states that "it is easy to prove (using deduction theorem and tautologies) that if $Γ⊢¬∀xψ$ then $Γ⊢¬∀x¬¬ψ$.

For clarification, the axioms of the system are:

$(α → (β → α))$ (A1)

$((α → (β → γ)) → ((α → β) → (α → γ)))$ (A2)

$((¬β → ¬α) → (α → β)) (A3)$

$(∀x_iα → α[t/x_i])$ if t is free for $x_i$ in α (A4)

$(∀x_i(α → β) → (α → ∀xiβ))$ if $x_i∈Free(α)$ (A5)

$∀x_i(x_i = x_i)$(A6)

$(x_i = x_j → (ϕ → ϕ′))$ where $ϕ$ is atomic and $ϕ′$ is obtained from $ϕ$ by replacing some occurrences of $x_i$ by $x_j$, (A7)

The inference rules are modus ponens and "generalisation":
($∀$) From $α$ infer $∀x_iα$ provided that $x_i$ doesn't appear in the premises

I have been trying to figure out how to prove this, but keep on failing - the section of the text that says it can be done using tautologies and DT makes me think that I shouldn't be using any of the rules other than A1,2&3.

I've considered trying to prove that $Γ⊢(∀x¬¬ψ→∀xψ)$ and then using axiom 3 to conclude, but here too I come to a dead end. My intuition is to then use A4 & argue by contradiction (using a proved tautology) in some way, but to get to a contradiction I need to use ($∀$ generalisation), and I can't do that as I don't know whether $x_i$ occurs free in the premises.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake - have fixed this!

Comment: Isn't there a rule similar to "$\Gamma, A\vdash \bot$ implies $\Gamma\vdash \neg A$" where $\bot$ is either a symbol meaning "false" or $B\land \neg B$ for any $B$ ?

Comment: You can derive a rule to that effect, yes - I'm unable to form a proof up to that point though.

Comment: This boils down to showing that $\vdash \forall x \ \neg \neg \psi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \psi(x)$ ... which should be an elementary proof involving quantifiers (yes, you *will* have to use the quantifier rules, since this is not a propositional logic tautology).  However, I am unclear how to do this in this system ... does your book have *any* example of a proof involving quantifiers?

Comment: In A5, I think you mean that $x_i$ is not free in $\alpha$.

Comment: Also your Gen rule is weird.  Hilbert style logics don't have premises (assumptions) like natural deduction style logics do.  So either you are saying $\dfrac{\alpha,~x \not \in \text{Free}(\alpha) }{\forall x ~\alpha}$, in which case the free variable restriction is unnecessary, or you are saying $\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash \alpha, ~x \not \in \text{Free}(\Gamma)}{\Gamma \vdash \forall x ~ \alpha}$, in which case the variable restriction is needed but the $\vdash$ part is not actually a part of the general logic.  I suspect your text means the second, but you should make sure.

Comment: @DanielV I've looked for close to an hour now to find an example of a universal proof in the Hilbert system, and I can't find any (in fact, I can;t find *any* actual proof in the Hilbert system that involves quantifiers ...).  Do you know how, for example, you would prove something elementary like $\vdash \forall x \ \neg \neg P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \ P(x))$?  Because that is what this proof boils down to ...

Comment: @MathsThatImo The Wikipedia page on the Hilbert system lists as an axiom $\vdash \forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x \ \varphi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \ \psi(x))$ ... did you maybe miss a $\forall$ in your A5?

Comment: @Bram28 I doubt many people "know" how to do arbitrary propositional logic in a Hilbert system.  It is a ridiculously complicated algorithm to prove a propositional tautology, if someone has it memorized....then I'm a little creeped out.  Hilbert system is more of a thing to just step back from and admire at a distance, if you want to actually prove stuff, natural deduction is more the tool for that.  I'll try to find a reference to the completeness of A1-A3 though.

Comment: @Bram28 https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/ lists A5 like he did, he is probably correct.

Comment: @DanielV Thanks for the feedback! I am actually fairly comfortable with the propositional logic part, but never really loked at the quantificational part. ... OK, so  I am still at a loss as to how to derive $\forall x \psi(x)$ from $\forall x \neg \neg \psi(x)$. Would $\forall x \ \neg \neg \psi(x) \rightarrow \neg \neg \psi(x)$ be an instance of A4?  I feel it isn't, and that I would have to do something like $\forall x \ \neg \neg \psi(x) \rightarrow \neg \neg \psi(a)$ ... but I must say I don't quite understand this '$t$ is free for $x$' phrase.

Comment: @DanielV And if I do have to do $\forall x \ \neg \neg \psi(x) \rightarrow \neg \neg \psi(a)$, then I can get to $\psi(a)$ ... but how would you put the $\forall x$ back on? It seems Generalization would only give me $\forall x \psi(a)$, i.e. some useless Null quantification ....

Comment: @Bram28 Read my comment starting "Also your Gen rule is weird".  Looking at the axioms, it seems impossible to establish any statement of the form $\forall x ~ P$ when $x$ is a free variable of $P$ just because no axioms is of that form and no inference allows such a form to be created.  Unless Gen doesn't intend to put a variable restriction on $\alpha$.  Also here; http://www.columbia.edu/~hg17/ViewMathLogic/view1-deductive-system.pdf .  It is really indirect but seems to get the point across (badly).  You want an algorithm that, assuming $P$ is a tautology, constructs a proof of $P$.

Comment: @DanielV Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking ... you can't seem to get the $\forall x$ in front of the $P(x)$.  Something seems to be wrong here ...

Comment: From ax: $\forall x \lnot \lnot \psi \to \lnot \lnot \psi$.

Comment: With tautology: $\lnot \lnot \psi \to \psi$ we have : $\forall x \lnot \lnot \psi \to \psi$.

Comment: Assume $\forall x \lnot \lnot \psi$ and derive $\psi$ and then "generalize" to $\forall \psi$. By Ded Th: $\forall x \lnot \lnot \psi \to \forall x \psi$. *Note*: here we can safely "generalize" because in the premise $\forall x \lnot \lnot \psi$ $x$ is not free.

Comment: Then "contrapose" it to $\lnot \forall x \psi \to \lnot \forall x \lnot \lnot \psi$.